# blender 2.60: precision modelling: how to see effect of grid subdivisions?

Tags: blender

I am using blender 2.60. In the 3D view I press B to bring up
the Properties window (View -> Properties) and look at the
Display section, where under Grid Floor I find the
"Subdivisions" option. When I change this value
nothing happen (the subdivisions are not visible).
When I try to move an object (in Object mode right
click a cube for example and press G, then click
CTRL + SHIFT, it still moves the cube in increments
of 0.10 if the "Scale" is set to 1.000.

My question is, how do I see the effect of setting
the subdivisions option under 3D Window -> View ->
Properties -> Display -> Subdivisions in blender 2.60?

Thanks,

John Goche

Comment: I've resolved this issue. You need to zoom into the grid to see the subdivision lines or else they will not be displayed.

Comment: Is this an appropriate question for SO? Could it be moved to some other SE site?

Comment: @JohnGoche If you have solver it, please formulate an official ansert and mark this question ans solved.